# Почему склеиваются элементы после перемещения jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Интересное поведение элементов.
Смысл в следующем.

1. уменьшаем браузер до ширины менее 800 пикселей.
2. элементы с классом btn перемещаются в блок row.
3. изменяем браузер до ширины более 800 пикселей.
4. элементы перемещаются обратно в блок c классом wrap.
5. проблема в том, что элементы склеиваются, хотя должны быть
   равномерно расположены по блоку wrap, как было в начале.

Как решить эту проблему???

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function change() {
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    if (width <= 800) {
      $('.main .btn').prependTo($('.row'));
    } else {
      $('.row .btn').prependTo($('.main .wrap'))
    };
  };
  change();
  $(window).resize(function() {
    change();
  });
});
```

```css
.row {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  display: table;
}

.row a {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.main {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.wrap {
  text-align: justify;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.wrap:after {
  display: inline-block;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
}

.excerpt {
  width: 45%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.btn {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="wrap">
    <a href="#" class="btn">Text1</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn">Text2</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn">Text3</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn">Text4</a>
    <div class="excerpt">
      <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. At aut culpa dolorum, et expedita facere itaque minus obcaecati officia perspiciatis repellat tempore tenetur veniam? Cum dolor ex fugiat illum veritatis.</span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ну что, классно. Сниппет потерли, зато пунктики красиво пронумерованы.

Comment: изменил сниппет)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут дело в том, что выравнивание рабоатет за счёт пробелов между кнопками, а кнопки перемещаются без пробелов и встают одной кучкой:

```css
p { text-align: justify; text-align-last: justify; }
```

```html
<p><button>Кнопка 1</button> <button>Кнопка 2</button> <button>Кнопка 3</button></p>
<p><button>Кнопка 1</button><button>Кнопка 2</button><button>Кнопка 3</button>  </p>
```

Проблему можно решить так:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function change() {
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    if (width <= 800) {
      $('.wrap-btns').prependTo($('.row'));
    } else {
      $('.wrap-btns').prependTo($('.main .wrap'))
    };
  };
  
  change();
  $(window).resize(function() {
    change();
  });
});
```

```css
.row {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  display: table;
}

.row .wrap-btns {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.row a {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.main {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.wrap {
  text-align: justify;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.wrap:after {
  display: inline-block;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
}

.excerpt {
  width: 45%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.btn {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="wrap">
    <span class="wrap-btns">
      <a href="#" class="btn">Text1</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn">Text2</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn">Text3</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn">Text4</a>
    </span>
    <div class="excerpt">
      <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. At aut culpa dolorum, et expedita facere itaque minus obcaecati officia perspiciatis repellat tempore tenetur veniam? Cum dolor ex fugiat illum veritatis.</span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```